# C# get all local ip address

Tags: c#, ip

I am using this code to find all ip address from all interface:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{    
    if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    {
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is on some pc it show the ip `169.254.x.x` (i know this is the "default" ip address.. useless here.)

if i do `ipconfig /all` i don't see this ip, but the real question is how can i avoid to show this ip?

Comment: Can you post your code that initialize `ni`?

Comment: did but joachim found a solution.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it would seem like a good fit to use [`IsDnsEligible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipaddressinformation.isdnseligible(v=vs.110).aspx) to eliminate the auto ip addresses;

```
foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
{
    if(!ip.IsDnsEligible)
        continue;

    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
    ...
```